# Is there an in-memory SQS?

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm looking for something that mimics the REST API of SQS and is usable for robust/non-flaky, small, logic/unit tests.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try ElasticMQ, https://github.com/adamw/elasticmq, which implements the SQS interface and has both in-memory and db-backed storages.

Comment: This is something I've been doing for a while now with a lot of success.  If Gradle is your build system I've written a plugin to automatically launch it as part of the build: http://bit.ly/1sbLoff

Answer (score 1):

[JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html) and [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) both provide similar queueing infrastructure.  Depending on your platform, you could use either of those technologies.  Both are robust.  MSMQ can provide an in-memory (non-transactional) queue in addition to a disk-backed, transactional queue.

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is another popular choice that should provide a superset of the SQS functionality.  I don't have direct experience with it, however.

It should be fairly straightforward to create a wrapper that mimics the SQS interface.

**UPDATE**

ActiveMQ provides a REST API.  However, the API is different than that of SQS.

You can either use that and wrap the API differences, or you can create a REST API of your own that exactly mirrors the SQS API and wraps any MQ system you wish.

http://activemq.apache.org/restful-queue.html

Comment: I should've been clearer. I'm looking for something with the same REST API as SQS, something that is essentially a drop-in replacement for the purposes of unit tests.

Comment: ActiveMQ offers a REST API (though a slightly *different* REST API than SQS).  You can either use that and wrap the API differences, or you can create a REST API of your own that exactly mirrors the SQS API and wraps any MQ system you wish.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to test _is_ the wrapper. The idea is to have th e wrapper use the fake in unit tests (so as to make its tests robust and fast) and have full integration tests for the fake (to ensure that its behavior continues to be the same as the underlying service).